# group by records and then get last ascending sorted record from each group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table:

```
| P_id | Month |  Year  |  Name  |
   624     09     2009    Test1
   600     10     2010    Test2
   624     10     2010    Test6
   600     09     2011    Test7
```

1. I want to order my table by `P_id` descending, `Year` ascending, then `Month` ascending
2. Based on the order I want the last record for each `P_id`.

After step 1 is run:

```
| P_id | Month |  Year  |  Name  |
  624     09      2009    Test1
  624     10      2010    Test6
  600     10      2010    Test2
  600     09      2011    Test7
```

Desired Output:

```
| P_id | Month |  Year  |  Name  |
   624     10     2010    Test6
   600     09     2011    Test7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `row_number`:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                  partition by p_id
                  order by year desc, month desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

The subquery is required because you can't use `row_number` directly in the `where` clause.

Comment: i can't use row_number() function in typed datasets.

Comment: What do you mean with typed dataset?

Comment: in VisualStudio, add new item-->VC#-->Data-->DataSet :)

Comment: You could run the query with `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` and [manually fill the dataset](http://forums.asp.net/t/1327460.aspx/1).  I suspect you could also edit the XML underlying the dataset to make it work with any query.  Or even better, switch to a [real ORM](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)